# How to rotate the image around the point of the upper left corner?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, anchor

I have a music player, I want the needle Image is on the disk when the player is playing. Rotating the image 45° around the point of the the upper left corner while the player isn't playing.The constraints of the needleImgView are `centerX to superView, top to superview = 40, size = (97,153)`

I have googled and found the following code:

```
func setAnchorPoint(_ anchorPoint:CGPoint, for view:UIView){

        let oldOrigin = view.frame.origin
        view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint
        let newOrigin = view.frame.origin

        var transition = CGPoint()
        transition.x = newOrigin.x - oldOrigin.x
        transition.y = newOrigin.y - oldOrigin.y
        view.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x - transition.x, y: view.center.y - transition.y)

    }
```

And with the following method to rotate the image:

```
if !player.isPlaying {
        setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x:40 / 97.0,y:40 / 153.0), for: needleImgView) // I'm NOT SURE the 40 is right.
        //needleImgView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.needleImgView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 4))
        }, completion: nil)

    }else{
        setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x:40 / 97.0,y:40 / 153.0), for: needleImgView) 
        //needleImgView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.needleImgView.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)

    }
```

I set `setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x:0 / 97.0,y:0 / 153.0), for: needleImgView)` or `needleImgView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)`,the result is that **the upper left corner point also move away**.

> [image: Screen Shot For The Left-top Point Moving Away]

**How to solve it ? Thx.**

Comment: you may try set anchor point to `(x: youPictureWidth / 2, y: 0)`

Comment: @NFLee it doesn't work with your method and the needleImgView will dismiss from the screen when the player is paused  .

Comment: yup, I made a mistake on anchor point, please check the answer I wrote.

Comment: I think you want.    yourView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:1.0, y: 0.0)

Comment: **INCREDIBLY EASIER WAY** https://stackoverflow.com/a/74722372/294884

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to solve it ---

1- you have to change the `40` by `0` .

```
setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x:0 / 97.0,y:0 / 153.0), for: needleImgView);
```

Change the Code ----

```
setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x:-10.0 / 97.0,y:0 / 153.0), for: YourImage)
```

for make same for your image change the value in X.

2- Take a Double size of image Like Clock and your pointer will be start from middle like clock's needle and you can rotate without anchor point. But it is the bad way to solve .

Try first one . it will help you, or feel free.

Comment: "I set the anchorPoint of the layer is (0,0),the result is that the upper left corner point also move away. "which has been described in the question.So your method one won't work and the result is as the second picture. And what I understand is that the anchorPoint(0,0) means the  the point of the the upper left corner.But i didn't work when I set `needleImgView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)`

Comment: you need to change in setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x:40 / 97.0,y:40 / 153.0), for: needleImgView) line only ... I check with background color of image it is working fine here. 40 replace with 0 ... and check

Comment: @ Abhishek Mishra  I have  tried it before, but it didn't work. I will post a screen shot in the question description.

Comment: @Ringo wait i will check just give me two hrs.

Comment: Okay,thx.Could you see the gif screen shot  in question? I have posted it ,but I can't have access to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `CABasicAnimation`.

0.5 of x of anchor point means in the middle of width, 0 of y means top of the height.

```
    imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0)

    let basic = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    basic.fromValue = NSNumber.init(value: 0)
    basic.toValue = NSNumber.init(value: -(Double.pi / 4))
    basic.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    basic.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    imageView.layer.add(basic, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: I have tried with the code, but it didn't work .The left-top point of the picture will move away (away from the original position)when rotating 45°.