# Rotate UIView around center where origin is different from x:0, y:0

Tags: ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform

let's assume i have created a custom UIView like that:

```
let view = CustomView((frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.width))
                                           ======
```

and I want to rotate it that way:

```
// Inside the CustomView    
self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
```

Then the view is not rotating around its center. But if the view is created like this

```
let view = CustomView((frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.width))
                                           =====
```

(I have marked the difference with =====)

the view is rotating around its center as expected. I understand that the rotation center can be adjusted via anchorpoint. But as far as I understand CGPoint(0,0) means "upper left corner", CGPoint(0.5, 0,5) means center, but this does not work if the y axis of the origin is diffrent from 0.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To set the `anchorPoint` use the following method

```
func setAnchorPoint(_ anchorPoint: CGPoint, for view: UIView) {
    var newPoint = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x, y: view.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y)
    var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width * view.layer.anchorPoint.x, y: view.bounds.size.height * view.layer.anchorPoint.y)

    newPoint = newPoint.applying(view.transform)
    oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(view.transform)

    var position: CGPoint = view.layer.position
    position.x -= oldPoint.x
    position.x += newPoint.x
    position.y -= oldPoint.y
    position.y += newPoint.y

    view.layer.position = position
    view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint
}
```

you can set anchor point like...

```
setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5), view: view)
```

And after that perform transformation. So it will transform view around its anchor point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A friend of mine just found a ugly hack to achieve my goal: I put a wrapper around my view with the same size. If I rotate the view inside the wrapper, the anchor point stays as expected although the origin of the wrapper was changed. I will test your solution when there is time for refactoring and making things tidy, no offense.

Answer (score 0):

### Far and away the best way to do this:

You want to spin a view, say "cat image".

1. Make a small UIView, "spinner". It must be **square**. Make it say 10x10. Make it red, say, while you are working.
2. Position spinner on the background *exactly where you want* the axle to be.
3. **Now make "cat image" a subview of spinner.**
4. Simply move catImage around, to the point you want to spin it from.

For example, you want to spin on the "top left" of the cat image: put that point of the cat image at the center of the spinner. (This is trivial with constraints.)

Now simply rotate the "spinner".

It's that easy.